# Slow Query in MongoDB with collection wide aggregate query using group

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I am having performance issues on the API I am developing using NodeJS+Express+MongoDB.

On running the aggregate with $match on particular product, the performance is good but for a open search it's really slow.

I want to run a group on two columns: country and exporter and then fetch the result limited to 3 results per group on country.

> Requirement: Total Count of unique exporters from each country along
>   with any 3 records from each country.

On running `explain()` on my `aggregate function` I am getting the following key pointers that flag about my queries being slow. Please correct me if I am wrong.

1. `"indexFilterSet": false`
2. `"winningPlan": {`
   `"stage": "COLLSCAN",`
   `"direction": "forward"`
   `},`

Ran the query on `9,264,947` records and time taken is about `32 seconds`.
I have tried using compound index as well as single field index but it's not helping at all, as I feel the index is not being used with `$match` being empty `{}`

Below is the query I am running on mongoDB using **mongoose** driver

```
Model.aggregate([
  {"$match" : query},
  { $group : {_id: {country: "$Country", exporter: "$Exporter"}, id: {$first: "$_id"}, product: { $first: "$Description" }}},
  { $group : {_id: "$_id.country", data: {$push: { id: "$id", company: "$_id.exporter", product: "$product" }}, count:{$sum:1}}},
  { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
  { 
    $project: { 
      "data": { "$slice": [ "$data", 3 ] },
      "_id": 1,
      "count": 1
    }
  },
]).allowDiskUse(true).explain()
```

where, **query** is dynamically build and is by default empty `{}` for a collection-wide search.
Indexed fields are

1. Compound Index: `{Country: 1, Exporter: 1}`
2. Text Index: `{Description: "text"}`

Full explain() response:

```
{
"success": "Successfull",
"status": 200,
"data": {
    "stages": [
        {
            "$cursor": {
                "query": {},
                "fields": {
                    "Country": 1,
                    "Description": 1,
                    "Exporter": 1,
                    "_id": 1
                },
                "queryPlanner": {
                    "plannerVersion": 1,
                    "namespace": "db.OpenExportData",
                    "indexFilterSet": false,
                    "parsedQuery": {},
                    "winningPlan": {
                        "stage": "COLLSCAN",
                        "direction": "forward"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans": []
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "country": "$Country",
                    "exporter": "$Exporter"
                },
                "id": {
                    "$first": "$_id"
                },
                "product": {
                    "$first": "$Description"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$_id.country",
                "data": {
                    "$push": {
                        "id": "$id",
                        "company": "$_id.exporter",
                        "product": "$product"
                    }
                },
                "count": {
                    "$sum": {
                        "$const": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort": {
                "sortKey": {
                    "count": -1
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": true,
                "count": true,
                "data": {
                    "$slice": [
                        "$data",
                        {
                            "$const": 3
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok": 1
}
}
```

Collection Size : **9,264,947 records & 10.2 GB**

Response Time : **32154 ms**

The query is getting slower as the size of my collection is increasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your *query* is `{}`, mongo engine skips the `$match` stage and go right into `$group`.  No index will be used.  You can verify above from `explain()` result.  The `$match` and `$sort` pipeline operators can take advantage of an index when they occur at the beginning of the pipeline.  Looking at your pipeline, you group them using *Country* and *Exporter*.  What you can do is to create an index on `{Country: 1, Exporter: 1}`, and use `$sort` on `{Country: 1, Exporter: 1}` as the first stage of the pipeline.  This will make `$group` more efficient.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But, nor the sorting is helping where I have country and exporter indexed. It just turns out that this is inevitable right now and we are not going to provide this feature to the end users where they can view a summary of overall records as that will be a huge collection.Thanks for all the information guys! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Using the aggregate like this means that mongodb have to go through all the record, then group the data (load 10 Gb), then slice the array it would have created.

Ofc the more your collection grow, the longer it is.

---

I think that instead of optimizing your actual request, it's worth reconsidering your approach of it.

---

I would first `find` every **country** name using one request. Then use one request for each **country** getting the first 3 **exporter**.

Using indexes on **country** and on **exporter**.

It's a lot more of request, but way smaller ones, which not requires to load all the data. With direct access to the data using proper indexes.

And considering there are not thousands of different country out there

Comment: One of the core requirement here is to find a summary of unique exporters in each country, and I feel running the group on country and exporters will be a required thing. Please let me know if there is any other way to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Is their a way to make use of defined index on these fields with `group` in aggregate?